# Search for string but ignore acute accent?

Tags: search

I'm trying to search using `M-s o` or `M-x occur`. The string that I'm searching for may or may not have an acute accent, eg, "Mart**í**n" or "Mart**i**n". The output is showing only the terms that has the acute accent (Mart**í**n), but I need the term without the acute accent (Mart**i**n) in the output also.

How do I get the search to ignore the accents?

Comment: Related question: [Incremental search for un/accented characters](http://superuser.com/questions/674619/incremental-search-for-un-accented-characters/675172#675172)

Comment: I copied the code in my .emacs file and it worked perfectly as I needed. Thank you, you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for this [regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html): `\bMart[ií]n\b`. the `\b`s match word boundries (so that you don't match "Martini" etc., and the `[ií]` matches `i` or `í`. There might be a better regexp, but I think this should work just fine if you are using it from `occur` or with `isearch-forward-regexp` (`C-M s` by default).

You can also simply search for the regular expression `\bMart.n\b`. The dot matches any single character except newline. If you do not have too many words like `Marten` the additional matches should not disturb you too much.

Comment: You beat me with your answer;-). So I just added some supplementary stuff from mine to yours. Hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Tobias I modified your additions slightly because the OP was asking specifically about `occur`

Comment: Elethan, Thank you for your reply. The regexp works perfectly, however I was searching for something like the comment above: " Related question: Incremental search for un/accented characters – Juancho 2 days ago ". Best Regards.

Comment: So it looks like you'll have to wait for emacs 25. Trying to implement a general solution in emacs 24 is likely going to be a very large undertaking, which is then rendered obsolete as soon as emacs 25 is out.